# Why Google GCP not support cross region UDP load balance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, vps, anycast

I like to build a DNS server with AnyCast ip.  try use the Google GCP to do the load balance.

But I find it only support TCP cross region load balance, why google not support cross region UDP load balance?

I like to Google AnyCast IP provide very fast response time at global level. buyvm.net also have the options but only work for EU and USA.  Is there any other options ?

Comment: Google does not offer a global load balancer supporting UDP. Questions asking why a vendor does not provide support for a desired feature should be directed to the vendor. @dattu's answer provides addition details.

Answer (score 1):

As per the GCP documentation[1], the scope of a network load balancer is regional, not global. This means that a network load balancer cannot span multiple regions. Within a single region, the load balancer services all zones.

This being said, Stack Overflow is used for technical questions and for any feature requests I would recommend creating a feature request in a public issue tracker[3].

Google’s Engineering team will review the feasibility of the feature request and will either implement or decline the feature with an explanation. There’s no ETA on how long a response to the feature request will take, hence you will need to monitor the link you create for updates.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network#protocols_scheme_and_scope
[2]https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list
[3]https://issuetracker.google.com/

Comment: I am ask here to see if some one can provide some technical explanation. Like udp anycast load banlance is hard to implement, or not Unreliable. And thanks for the tips,  I will try create a feature request.

Comment: Due to the reason it's more related to the architectural design. I would recommend creating a feature request and one of the support agents will provide you details accordingly.